# Unexpected output from a function using closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

```js
const run = initialize;
run(1);
run(1);
run(1);
function initialize(index) {
    console.log('runs only once');
    return function(index) {
        console.log('useless code to use closure to make sure initialize only runs once');
        return index;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, but I am not exactly sure why, because the code below works as intended and only runs the code inside the outer function once while running the inner function several times.

```js
const getIndex = bigStuff();
getIndex(500);
getIndex(600);
getIndex(700);
function bigStuff(index) {
    const myArray = new Array(300).fill('3');
    console.log('created once');
    return function(index) {
        console.log('calling several times');
        return myArray[index];
    }
}
```

The second chunk of code returns:

```
created once
calling several times
calling several times 
calling several times
```

While the first chunk of code returns:

```
runs only once
runs only once
runs only once
```

Can someone explain to me what the Javascript engine does in the background? Because I feel the output will differ depending on what's inside the inner and outer functions when you're using closures.

Comment: You're not invoking the function here, `const run = initialize` you just referenced the function, where as in second snippet you invoked the function which returns a function and you call it several time

Comment: Initialize is a function that takes a param and returns a function that takes a param. You'd need to do `run(1)(x);`

Comment: did you forget to include `()` on your `initialize()` call in the top example? Because if not, you have a function reference there and are just calling `initialize` 3 times when you do `run(1)` multiple times

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, I forgot the (), but adding the () still results in the same output.

Comment: I'd check it again; it should work now though your function signatures are confusing.

Comment: @gosa it produces the expected output once you put `()` at proper place.

Comment: Nevermind, seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const run = initialize()

run(1); 

run(1); 

run(1); 

function initialize(index) {


    console.log('runs only once');

    return function(index) { 

        console.log('useless code to use closure to make sure initialize only runs once');

        return index;

    } 

}
```

By changing the first line to actually invoke `initialize` and return a function, the above runs as expected